# Rails: Not permitting :id of nested model leads to automatic generation of new instances. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a conceptual doubt regarding nested models, and I hope I will make myself clear in this question.

I have 3 models, **A**, **B**, and **C**. **A** accepts nested attributes for **B** and **C**. On AController#new I write @a = A.new, @a.b.build, @a.c.build (I will share the code below).

Defining **A**'s parameters, I permit **B**'s parameters and **C**'s parameters. **Problem: I had forgotten to permit C's :id**.

Thus, whenever I would edit an instance of **A** on my website (say, at '**/a/1/edit**'), it would automatically create new instances of **C**.

Diagnosing the problem was very easy (I just spotted that **C**'s :id was missing, and inferred that it was the issue), **but I wonder why that happens**. Does anyone have insight? Details of my code follow.

**a.rb**

```
has_many :b
has_many :c    
accepts_nested_attributes_for :b
accepts_nested_attributes_for :c
```

**a_controlle.rb**

```
def new
    @a = A.new
    @a = @a.b.build
    @a = @a.c.build
end

def edit
    @a = A.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    if A.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(a_params)
    #SOME CODE
end

def create
    @a = A.new(a_params)
    #SOME CODE
end

private

def a_params
    params.require[:a].permit(:a_name, b_attributes: [:id, :b_name],
    c_attributes: [:c_name]) ## SEE, I had forgotten C's :id.
end
```

And both A/new.html.erb and A/edit.html.erb have fields_for B and C.

So, does anyone know why anytime I would access A/[:id]/edit it would generate new instances of C, given that I had forgotten to permit its :id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. If one use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :c` and sends attributes for `C`, that object is created if there is no `:id` param in params for `C` (in `c_attributes`).

So I suppose you have a form with nested attributes for `C` and `B` models and every time you submit your form you send your attributes for `A`,`B` and `C` objects. Every time you send your `c_attributes` without `:id` new object is created.

You can experiment and create form for only `A` oject or `A` and `B` objects to see that no `C` objects are created or edited.

I hope that helps you a bit to understand what's going on.